# How to create a dropdownlist with the next 30 dates?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dropdownlist in MVC that shows the next 30 dates and the chosen date is passed into a constructor with other details for an Event. Below is what I currently have but it's not working. I've looked at dropdownlistfor but didn't understand the intellisense within VisualStudio

In my model:

```
     public static List<DateTime> GetLstOfDates()
    {

        List<DateTime> dateList = new List<DateTime>();
        dateList =  Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(d => DateTime.Today.AddDays(d)).ToList();

        return dateList;
```

in my controller:

```
            // GET: Events/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.OrganizationId = new SelectList(db.Organizations, "OrganizationId", "OrganizationName");

        ViewBag.Dates = Event.GetLstOfDates ();

        return View();
    }
```

and in my create view:

```
 @Html.Label("Select Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Date", (SelectList)ViewBag.Dates, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Is How You Use DropDownListFor
in Your Controller

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            List<int> ListOfAnyThing = new List<int>() { 1,5,7,8,9,2 };
            ViewBag.MyList = new SelectList(ListOfAnyThing);
            return View();
        }
```

In Your View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyProperty, ViewBag.MyList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

This Way The Value You Choose In The Drop Down List Will Be Assigned To The Property MyProperty Of The Model You Are Going To Send Back To a Controller

Comment: So the main thing I never learned was that you had to put the list inside of a select list in the controller? Interesting. Thanks for the help! Can I limit to only showing the Date part of it though? What you suggested works great, but it also shows the times, which is something I don't need for this drop down.

Comment: Trying Converting Your Dates To String Like This 
MyDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
And Then Instead Of Passing A List Of DateTime To The new SelectList() Constructor Pass a List Of Strings